# How to manage data that is part of same object but is placed in different parts of the DOM in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a single page that has a form called search criteria. this form sits on the left side of the page and manages what criteria is posted back to the server. I can easily wrap this form in it's own controller. however I have a drop down in a completely different place in the page which is also part of the criteria that is sent to the server.

right now I have created two different controllers for each section and I also have a factory which manages the combined search criteria, when the page first is loaded or when it changes in any of these two controllers.

am I taking the right approach or is there a better way?

is there a way to use the data from the factory directly in my bindings in the dom?

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the right approach. DOM bindings would appear more direct if you defined a directive that just inserted the current value of the service/factory.

Comment: This is the right approach. You should never bind service directly to view. it should be via controller. And as the data need to be shared between multiple controllers, then service is the best place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you are in right direction, Take a look at the Plunkr which I have created for you, In which I added service in scope variable which provides access to service variable. And object inside the service will be easily accessible on view.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1" style="float: left">
    Upper Section
    <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]" ng-class="{green: dataService.data.selected == i, red: dataService.data.selected != i}" 
    ng-click="dataService.data.selected = i" ">{{i}}</div>
    {{dataService}}
<div>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl2 " style="float: right ">
    Bottom Section
    <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5] " ng-class="{green: dataService.data.selected==i , red: dataService.data.selected !=i } " 
     ng-click="dataService.data.selected=i ">{{i}}</div>
    {{dataService}}
<div>
```

**Code**

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, dataService){
  $scope.dataService =  dataService;
})
.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope,dataService){
  $scope.dataService =  dataService;
}).
service('dataService', function(){
  this.data = {};
  this.getData = function(){
    return this.data;
  };
  this.setData = function(val){
    this.data = val;
  };
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kdgvizR5tBsBuOEOrqvI?p=preview)

Comment: How does `ng-click="dataService.data.selected = i` change the value without calling `setData`?

Comment: @RustyShackleford because controller scope has full copy of service data, you could also use `setData` method .

Comment: is `.selected` an implicit way to call `setData`. I don't see else how `data` get's updated.

Comment: @RustyShackleford see this it is updating using `setData` http://plnkr.co/edit/BwaUfDLoqQIvSliq72P8?p=preview , in set data you need to pass object like `{selected: i}` , might be you missed it

Comment: I see now, the link above does not have the setData method call

Comment: @RustyShackleford I can see the changes, I changed ng-click to this `ng-click="dataService.setData({selected: i})"`